# Hamcrest. Match item in collection with 2 specific property values

Tags: java, spring-boot, matcher, hamcrest

I have a test with a collection of SpecialObject as result. SpecialObject has "name" and "surname" as properties. I want to test if the collection contains a specialObject with 2 specific properties, "name=myname" and "surname=lastname".

Here is what I have tried without success:

```
assertThat(result, Matchers.<SpecialObject>hasItem(
    allOf(
          hasProperty("name", equalTo("myname")),
          hasProperty("surname", equalTo("lastname"))
));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `both` matcher to check if both properties has excepcted values.

```
    Assert.assertThat(result, Matchers.<SpecialObject>hasItem(
            Matchers.both(hasProperty("name", equalTo("myname")))
                    .and(hasProperty("surname", equalTo("lastname")))));
```